# How to open new view (call an activity) from options menu defined in XML? (android)

Tags: android, android-activity

I cant seem to open a new view from an options menu item. The program keeps crashing as it applies the intent and listener to the item. I am just beginning, so please be nice.

The current view is mnfsms, and the view I am trying to open is mnfsms_settings. I am developing for 1.5.

Could someone please help me get the menu working.

The menu (called options_menu.xml):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/settings_button"
          android:title="Settings"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences" />
    <item android:id="@+id/about_button"
          android:title="About"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces" />
</menu>
```

The main view (called mnfsms.java):

```
package com.example.mnfsms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class mnfsms extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /*        OnClickListener myocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v){
  Intent myi = new Intent(mnfsms.this, mnfsms_settings.class);
  startActivity(myi);
 }
};*/    
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    MenuItem mi_settings = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    mi_settings.setIntent(new Intent(this, mnfsms_settings.class));

    return true;
}
}
```

The manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.mnfsms"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:name=".mnfsms" android:label="@string/main_window_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
      <activity android:name=".mnfsms_settings" android:label="string/main_window_name">
            </activity>
        </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

The stacktrace:

```
01-06 15:07:58.045: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.example.mnfsms.mnfsms.onCreateOptionsMenu(mnfsms.java:30)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2038)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:421)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:664)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1278)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1735)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2188)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2158)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1490)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
01-06 15:07:58.055: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: FYI, when posting your code, it's much easier to copy-paste into the editor, highlight the whole block of code, and click the "Code Sample" button on the bar. This will let you post XML. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at the code to see what you did, because you also got syntax highlighting for me.

Comment: Also don't forget to say in the Manifest which classes are you going to use in order to implement intents ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace the `findViewById` call with `menu.findItem`

Comment: Thanks. I went through another debug and realised the findViewById was not working and was not assigning mi_settings. I was looking for the right command.

Thanks Heaps

Answer (score 0):

Your code and XML looks about right.  However you're not calling `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()` at the start of your method.

Can you post the stack trace you get when the app crashes? At what point does it crash? When you press <kbd>Menu</kbd> while in this Activity?

Comment: Added stacktrace. It crashes when I press "Menu" while in the activity.

Answer (score -1):

you can use  MenuItem mi_settings = menu.getItem(0) not MenuItem mi_settings = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.settings_button);  it is work find.